# Cannot login to Windows Server Essentials with administrator

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remmina

I have Windows Server 2016 Essentials and created two users. Both users are in the `Administrators`, `Domain Admins` and `Domain Users groups`.

However, one can log in, the other can't. When trying to log in using Remmina (a remote desktop client for Linux), I get "Unable to connect to 1.2.3.4". When issuing an incorrect password I get a different error, so I know the password is correct.

The other user works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer Windows server editions force the user to login via Network Level Authentication (NLA) by default. This is explained [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/959728/how-do-you-configure-nla-for-rdp-in-windows-server-2012) or [this Technet article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732713(v=ws.11)). Due to this, a user that needs to change it's password cannot login, or even change the password. It's not an issue per se that is caused by Remmina.

This was implemented by Microsoft for security reasons, but you can turn it of (see superuser link above) or to try and give the user a webpage so that you can facilitate this.
A great how-to on the webpage is given [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1196477/allow-users-to-change-expired-password-via-remote-desktop-connection) here by Twisty Impersonator. It is an official Microsoft way of getting around this.